# Why GattDeviceService.FromIdASync() fails to finish?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-10-universal, hm-10

I'm developing a Windows 10 Universal Application to communicate with an embedded system via a HM-10 chip.

**What I did try and other circumstances**

The chip is set up, there is no problem connecting to it. From an iPhone application for these devices, I can due two-way messaging via Arduino Serial window, and the iPhone application. 
My computer can also see it, and can connect to it from a sample application provided by Microsoft.

Before running, it is paired and connected in Bluetooth Settings. I also tried without pairing and connecting, but it was not discovered by DeviceInformation then.

The MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace App1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {

        public List<string> deviceList = new List<string>();
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Debug.WriteLine("A");
            var taskDevices = getDevices();
            Task.WaitAll(taskDevices);
            Debug.WriteLine("B");

        }
        public async Task<List<string>> getDevices()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("C");
            foreach (DeviceInformation di in await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(GattDeviceService.GetDeviceSelectorFromUuid(GattServiceUuids.GenericAccess), null))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("D");
                Debug.WriteLine(di.Name);
                Debug.WriteLine(di.Id);
                Debug.WriteLine(di.IsEnabled);
                var bleDevice = await GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync(di.Id);
                Debug.WriteLine("E");
                // Add the dvice name into the list.  
               // deviceList.Add(bleDevice.Name);
            }
            return deviceList;
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

I did my search and I realised the manifest needs an addition to have Bluetooth capability.

Package.appxmanifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"  xmlns:m2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp">
  <Identity Name="acbf6f03-e62b-4d1e-8c25-9f649ca5af4c" Publisher="CN=Boomkin" Version="1.0.0.0" />
  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="acbf6f03-e62b-4d1e-8c25-9f649ca5af4c" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>App1</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>Boomkin</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="App1.App">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="Histamine Control Panel" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png" Description="App1" BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png">
        </uap:DefaultTile>
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.genericAttributeProfile">
      <m2:Device Id="any">
        <m2:Function Type="serviceId:00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"/>
      </m2:Device>
    </m2:DeviceCapability>
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

I have tried many other versions, added and deleted internetclient and bluetooth capabilities, without any success. My current guess that the problem is around here.

**The problem**

As the question states the FromIdAsync part doesn't return anything. Not even null (as I saw in many other questions here), it just does not finish and the thread exists eventually.

**Log**

```
A
C
D
HIST
\\?\BTHLEDevice#{00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_f45eabaaf694#8&2782425b&13&0006#{6e3bb679-4372-40c8-9eaa-4509df260cd8}
True
```

Then after waiting for a while

```
The thread 0x3c6c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Thank you and I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
Task.WaitAll(taskDevices);
```

[Blocking on asynchronous code causes a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). The proper resolution is to use [async all the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

In your specific case, you need to (synchronously, immediately) create your view in a "loading" state - however you want that to look. Then, when the asynchronous code completes, *update* your view to a "loaded" state. See my MSDN article on [async data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) for more information.